# MSI Installer for 64bit Windows Platform(Visual Studio)

Tags: windows, windows-installer

I have a COM component which I wish to deploy in a 64bit environment. There are multiple applications using this COM component. Some of these applications are 32-bit and others are 64-bit. 
So while creating an installer, I which to bundle both the 32-bit and 64-bit versions of my COM dll.
In my first attempt, while building the installer project, I get a lot of warnings:

Ex. WARNING: Two or more objects have the same target location ('[payload_ul]\msvcp90.dll')

The warnings above are to do with merge modules. I have checked, but no multiple merge modules are present.

Also while the projects compiles successfully though with the warnings, while testing I found that the 64 bit module had failed to register.

The MSI was marked for x64 platform.

Can anyone provide pointers for the correct way to do this?

Comment: You need both 32 and 64 bit MSVC C++ runtime, which is why you are merging that module twice.

Comment: hmmm... is there a way to avoid that.. can the installer be better organized? Also there is the issue with the component not being registered.

Comment: The component is not being registered because only one of the runtime DLLs is installed because of the conflict, which makes your component DLL fail to load from regsvr32.

Comment: The easiest way to avoid all of this trouble is to link against the C++ runtime statically and omit the dependency on the runtime DLL. That is not a generic solution, obviously, but "good enough" if you just want to ship something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MSI doesn't support mixed x86 and x64 installers (check out this blog: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/heaths/archive/2008/01/15/different-packages-are-required-for-different-processor-architectures.aspx ). There are ways to "workaround" it, but eventually you will be bitten one way or another.